# send parameter using submit, PHP

Tags: php, html

1. `<input type = "submit" name = "ok" value = "<? php echo $ _POST ['no'];?>">`
2. `<input type = "submit" name = "ok" value = "ok">`

what if I want to send parameters using submit. if i use the number 2 then value on submit = "ok", but the parameters that will be sent is "ok". but when using the number 1, then the value on submit depending on the value of $ _POST ['no'], but managed to send parameters.

I want to ask how can I make permanent value "ok" but sends the parameters depend on $ _POST ['no']?

Comment: please show more code ??

Comment: Please clarify your question more

Comment: I don't understand your question. However, it is not a good practise to use the `value` attribute on a submit input element, it can cause problems in old browsers. I recommend using a `<input type=hidden>` element instead.

Comment: Your question is very not clear. Please improve your English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second `<input>` element to maintain the value of `$_POST['no']`. HTML provides the `<input type="hidden">` input for this explicit purpose:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ok" value="<?= $_POST['no'] ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="ok">
```

Answer (score 4):

from what I understand you are looking for a hidden field:

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "someField" value = "<? php echo $ _POST ['no'];?>">
<input type = "submit" name = "ok" value = "ok">
```